# Fetch files from SVN history by specific criterias

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm trying to find approach which allows me to find files in Subversion history by next criterias:

- Files which were modified in specific time interval
- Files which were modified by specific author at least once

To put it in a nutshell, I'm trying to find all files which were modified by my team in last 2 months. How could I perform it?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic SVN solution (command-line) or in some application (e.g. TortoiseSVN) ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a way this can be achieved in TortoiseSVN:

**Files which were modified in specific time interval**

1. Open SVN log (RMB > SVN menu > Show log)
2. Under `Show all` select a `Show range` option and fill in dates range you need
3. If you shift-select all the revisions in upper frame you will see all files which were changed in them in a frame below
4. You can also as well use `Statistics` to see charts (e.g. `Commits by author`)

**Files which were modified by specific author at least once**

1. Same as above
2. Same as above
3. Sort revisions list by author and shift-select commits made by author to see list of files he has changed

Comment: I believe that this approach works but unfortunately it appears that I have no chance to use TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 0):

On the command-line, you can specify revisions as date ranges instead, and SVN will look up the real revision numbers for you. So `svn log` can give you a list of revisions within certain dates, see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates for details.